# Highlight a portion of stacked bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a stacked bar plot in ggplot2 using the code:

```
shared_private_1k <- read.table("my_data_file_name", header=TRUE)  
p <- ggplot(shared_private_1k, aes(x=popu,y=shared_SNVs,fill=type)) +  
 geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.5) + labs(x="Populations", y="% Shared and Private")
```

The graph looks like this:

[image: Graph]

I want to add small blue bars within each `shared portion` (e.g I have added in Population 1 by an image editor just to show what I require). The length of this small blue bar represents a value which is actually less than the `shared` value. So it will fall within the `shared` bar.
Thanks for help.

Comment: how do you determine the y value of the small blue bars?

Comment: These are present in a separate data table, such that: `dele_greater_freq <- read.table("my_data_file2", header=TRUE)`. In this data, `x` contain same populations, but `y` has values smaller than `stacked shared value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are just looking to add a second smaller width bar overlaying your stacked bars. You could try something like this, which I illustrated her with the mtcars dataset.

```
mtcars$shared <-  mtcars$mpg*.4 # create a dummy variable representing shared
ggplot(mtcars) +  
  geom_bar(aes(x=as.character(cyl),y=mpg,fill=gear),stat="identity", width = 0.5) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=as.character(cyl),y=shared),stat="identity", width = 0.2, fill="blue") +
  labs(x="Cylinder", y="Miles / Gallon")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Code written and edited by `Wyldsoul` and `Axeman` respectively remains good, if y value of `blue bars` are from the same data set. But in this case, these were from another date file, so this was solved by defining `data=my_data_file2` in the second geom_bar() function, which overlayed the previous bars. So, the final code is:

```
p <- ggplot(shared_private_1k) + geom_bar(aes(x=popu,y=shared_SNVs,fill=type), stat="identity", width = 0.5)
p + geom_bar(data=my_data_file2, aes(x=popu, y=shared_multiply_by_proportion), stat="identity", width=0.1, fill="blue")
```